# HTML issue with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create the following within bootstrap

[image]

This is my current markup

```
   <section id="about" class="module" style="background-color:#5690AF">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/hackit.png" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
                        <img src="~/Content/Images/faceCup.png" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color:#EA6000">
                        <img src="~/Content/Images/bernardApron.png" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="background-color: #6A9574">
                    <img src="~/Content/Images/gardenHeart.png" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Yet when I run the project I get

[image]

After looking at my HTML I assumed what I have was correct but sadly it renders completely different to what I expected, would someone be able to give me a hand.

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you start a row, there's always 12 columns in there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

```
<section id="about" class="module" style="background-color:#5690AF">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/hackit.png" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 text-center" style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
                        <img src="~/Content/Images/faceCup.png" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 text-center" style="background-color:#EA6000">
                        <img src="~/Content/Images/bernardApron.png" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="background-color: #6A9574">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <img src="~/Content/Images/gardenHeart.png" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```